# When compiling chromeium, I encounter the problem of ‘’lld-link: error: undefined symbol:‘’

Tags: windows-10, chromium

When I compile chromium on win10, I entered `autoninja -C out\Default chrome`, and then ran to

```
[1/542] LINK(DLL) blink_core.dll blink_core.dll.lib blink_core.dll.pdb', and reported an error: ' FAILED: blink_core.dll blink_core.dll.lib blink_core.dll.pdb
..\..\third_party\llvm-build\Release+Asserts\bin\lld-link.exe "/OUT:./blink_core.dll" /nologo -libpath:..\..\third_party\llvm-build\ Release+Asserts\lib\clang\18\lib\windows "-libpath:../../../../../Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Enterprise/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.37 .32822/ATLMFC/lib/x64" "-libpath:../../../../../Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Enterprise/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.37.32822/lib /x64" "-libpath:../../../../../Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/lib/10.0.22621.0/ucrt/x64" "-libpath:../ ../../../../Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/lib/10.0.22621.0/um/x64" /MACHINE:X64 "/IMPLIB:./blink_core.dll.lib" / DLL "/PDB:./blink_core.dll.pdb" "@./blink_core.dll.rsp"
lld-link: error: undefined symbol: __declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl blink::delivery_type_names::Init(void)
>>> referenced by .\..\..\third_party\blink\renderer\core\core_initializer.cc:134
>>> obj/third_party/blink/renderer/core/core/core_initializer.obj:(public: virtual void __cdecl blink::CoreInitializer::Initialize(void))

lld-link: error: undefined symbol: __declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl blink::fetch_initiator_type_names::Init(void)
>>> referenced by .\..\..\third_party\blink\renderer\core\core_initializer.cc:138
>>> obj/third_party/blink/renderer/core/core/core_initializer.obj:(public: virtual void __cdecl blink::CoreInitializer::Initialize(void))......
```

I have searched, nothing Find a solution, ask for help.

I've tried adding the compile option '-j1', but it still doesn't work, and restarted the computer, still the same

Comment: The linker is unable to find `blink::delivery_type_names::Init` etc. Either you made some changes to `BUILD.gn` or the implementations are missing. Did you run `gclient sync` to pull third-party dependencies? Blink is a third-party dependency.